# Extract strings from a textbox to a listbox

Tags: c#, string, textbox

```
 {
     int numlines = txtbox.Lines.Count();

     string[] l = txtbox.Lines;

     for (int i = 0; i <= numlines; i++)
     {
         string lona = l[i].Substring(25, 12);
         lstbox.Items.Add(lona);
     }
 }
```

Hi, I want to move some elements from a textbox to a listbox using a for loop and a substring method. This is the code i tryed and it causes an exception while running it in a loop.

Comment: What is the *exception*, please? At least, `i < numlines` in the loop (please, note `<` instead of `<=`)

Answer (score 1):

Since C# collections are *zero based*, correct `for` loop uses `< Count`, not `<= Count` condintion:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < numlines; i++) // i < numlines, not i <= numlines
 {
     ...
 }
```

Let's *simplify* the routine and *get rid* of `for` loop: we add `each` line which is *long enough* (so we'll be able to get a `Substring`):

```
 foreach (string line in txtbox.Lines) {
   if (line.Length >= 25 + 12)
     lstbox.Items.Add(line.Substring(25, 12)); 
 }
```